# ProcessPoolExecutor logging failed?

Tags: python, logging, python-multiprocessing

I'm creating a multi-processing program to process multiple batches, but my logging is unable to record the batch into log file, only root log.info will be recorded, how can set logging to properly print to log file?

The log will only print such a line "INFO:root:this is root logging
"

```
import logging
import concurrent.futures
def process_batchs():
    batches = [i for i in range(100)]
    logging.basicConfig(filename=r'doc\test_ProcessPoolExecutor.log', filemode='w+',level=logging.DEBUG)
    logging.info('this is root logging')
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(10) as e:
        futures = []
        for batch in batches:
            future = e.submit(f, batch)
            futures.append(future)
        while True:
            dones = [future.done() for future in futures]
            if all(dones):
               results = [future.result() for future in futures]
               print results
               break
def f(batch):
    # do some thing
    logging.info('this is sub logging' + str(batch))
    return batch


if __name__ == '__main__':
    process_batchs()
```

running on windows/python2.7

Comment: hmm, this is strange, I guess I get a different output because of a unix system. (both logs are working fine). It looks like windows has a different behavior in this case.

Comment: @Taras, any idea to solve this inside logging?

Comment: I guess that logging file is blocked somehow, but I have no idea to be honest. I've spent 30 minutes trying to get **it running on windows and I have no desire to continue to do anything on that system ;(
Good luck, man!

Comment: @TarasMatsyk got a solution here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

logging is using different instance in each sub process, and not able to write into the same file. Apply follow fix will solve the problem, but I think a better solution might be singleton pattern by using logging.getlogger('abc')?

```
import logging
import concurrent.futures
def process_batchs():
    batches = [i for i in range(100)]
    logging.basicConfig(filename=r'test_ProcessPoolExecutor.log', filemode='w+',level=logging.DEBUG)
    logging.info('this is root logging')
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(10) as e:
        futures = []
        for batch in batches:
            future = e.submit(f, batch)
            futures.append(future)
        while True:
            dones = [future.done() for future in futures]
            if all(dones):
               results = [future.result() for future in futures]
               print results
               break
def f(batch):
    # do some thing
    # Here is the trick, notice here!!!
    ########
    logging.basicConfig(filename=r'test_ProcessPoolExecutor.log', filemode='w+',level=logging.DEBUG)
    ########
    logging.info('this is sub logging' + str(batch))
    return batch


if __name__ == '__main__':
    process_batchs()
```